# MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank

Tags: c, mpi

I got the above mentioned error on running the following program in C. The program uses 3-d hypercube topology to find sum of all elements of an 8-element array. It uses MPI library.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rank, n, src, dest;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n);
    int tag = 100;
    int receive;
    int array[8] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80};

    if (rank&1 == 1)
        MPI_Send(&array[rank], 1, MPI_INT, rank-1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(&receive, 1, MPI_INT, rank+1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        array[rank] += receive;
        if (rank&2 == 1)
            MPI_Send(&array[rank], 1, MPI_INT, rank-2, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        else
        {
            MPI_Recv(&receive, 1, MPI_INT, rank+2, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            array[rank] += receive;
            if (rank&4 == 1)
                MPI_Send(&array[rank], 1, MPI_INT, rank-4, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            else
            {
                MPI_Recv(&receive, 1, MPI_INT, rank+4, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                array[rank] += receive;
                printf("\n%d \n", array[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Used 8 processes by calling

```
mpirun -n 8 ./a.out
```

Runtime error message:

> ```
> An error occurred in MPI_Recv  
> reported by process [3153068033,6]  
> on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD  
> MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank  
> MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,  
> and potentially your MPI job)
> ```

Comment: There is an error in the "tree logic" of your `Recv`s. Something is attempting to send to a negative rank or a rank greater than 7. I would write out which logic branches each rank hits.

Comment: How many tasks do you use for your test ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet 8 tasks. Also updated details for the same in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an error in the way you use bitwise and.

For example, it should be

```
if (rank & 2)
```

instead of

```
if (rank&2 == 1)
```

`rank&2` is a bitwise and, which means its value is either `0` or `2` (and it is never `1`)

Comment: Thanks for this. And I think I should really pay more attention to the logic before asking doubt. This will a silly mistake.

Comment: @GauravSingh can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200986/try-to-convert-c-program-to-mpi-program-but-error-occur