# srun: error: distribution type `em' is not recognized

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mpi

I wrote a c program for this equation,

[image]

I am trying to write down a mpi programming for the above formula.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<mpi.h>
double sum(int n);

int main(void){
int my_rank,comm_sz, n=1024;
double local_sum, total_sum;
int source;
int local_n;
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);

local_n=n/comm_sz;
local_sum=sum(local_n);

if ( my_rank != 0) {
 MPI_Send (&local_sum , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD ) ;
}

else{
 total_sum = local_sum;
 for(source=1;source<comm_sz;source++){
 MPI_Recv (&local_sum , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , source , 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE ) ;
 total_sum+=local_sum;
}
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;

}

double sum(int n){
int i;
double cal_sum=0;
for (i =0;i <= n;i++) {
  cal_sum = cal_sum + 4*(pow (-1, i))/((2*i)+1);
}
return cal_sum;
}
```

run time Error:

```
srun: error: distribution type `em' is not recognized
```

Any idea when I get this error?

My srun command:  `srun -p node -n 4 -N 1 -pty -mem 1000 -t 10:00 bash`

Comment: You're sending `sum`, but no one puts a value in it. But your real problem is `for (i<source) MPI_Recv( /*from:*/ source )`. If you catch my drift.

Comment: Instead of debugging this, take this opportunity to learn about `MPI_Reduce()` and rewrite your code.

Comment: Even after change it correctly I still got error. Sum= 0. The value of sum will be calculated within the for loop.

Comment: your code does not compile. (well, it does if you compile with `-Dsource=MPI_ANY_SOURCE`, but then it hangs...). Please read again the first two comments and if you are still stuck, post your updated code, your compile command line and your `mpirun` command line

Comment: I stand corrected, your code won't hang if you compiled with -Dsource=MPI_PROC_NULL` :-D

Comment: I have added the error that I got. It was a compilation time error so I can not run the program. I have also modify my code.

Comment: you likely need to pass `-lm` to the linker (for the `pow` symbol). That being said, your code makes very little sense. Take a deep breath and describe your parallelization strategy (start with `n=4` and `comm_sz=2`) in plain English.

Comment: -lm helped me to compile the code then again I got this error at runtime

Comment: you're welcome. I have no intention to spoon-feed you the solution, so good speed!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have change my code. But the error still there. Can you please take a look.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout  I have change the code but the error remain same. Can you share your opinion.

Comment: Debug your code. If the message says "invalid rank", print out all ranks before you do the MPI call.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I got a new error. Any idea when I get this type of error?

Comment: That's a SLURM issue, try using `mpirun` instead. Your parallelization strategy is very surprising btw ...

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet your hint makes my day. I changed in my code which is weird to you. Now, the code is running. I need to print some statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can deduce the error simply by reading the error message and checking the corresponding part in your code.

Error Message:

```
[node070:100103] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[node070:100103] *** MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank
```

Look at `MPI_Recv` in your code and you can see that you are receiving from `rank n`. There is no rank n. The maximum rank number you can get when size `n` is `n-1`.

```
MPI_Recv (&sum , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , n , 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE ) ;
```

You should replace `n` with `i` in your MPI_Recv.

Comment: that's necessary but that won't be enough!

Comment: @j23 I have change the code as per my understanding. I believe now it is more sensible than the previous one but the errors still persist. If you have any idea please share here.